# Chatbot in Microsoft Teams not sending Important flag messages

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a working chatbot on Microsoft teams, in which I'm sending users messages from it using two ways as appears in the following two code snippets.

**Bot framework sdk:**

```
public static async Task SendTemplateToUser(SendTeamsMessage message, string summary, ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var cardAttachment = new Attachment()
    {
        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message.MessageBody),
        Properties = new JObject
        {
            ["Importance"] = "high"
        }
    };
    var messageActivity = MessageFactory.Attachment(cardAttachment);
    messageActivity.Summary = summary;
    messageActivity.Importance = message.IsUrgent ? "high" : "normal";
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(messageActivity, cancellationToken);
}
```

**Graph API:**

```
var messageBody = new ChatMessage()
{
    Subject = "Testing Message",
    Body = new ItemBody()
    {
        Content = messageTemplate,
        ContentType = BodyType.Html
    },
    MessageType = ChatMessageType.Message,
    Importance = ChatMessageImportance.Normal,
    Locale = "en-US"
};

await graphClient.Chats[createdChat.Id].Messages.PostAsync(messageBody, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

The thing is, using graph API, the important flag on the message received is actually being added. But it's not working when using bot framework sdk.

Is there any way to add the important flag into teams message using bot framework sdk??

Comment: In the second/graph snippet you are setting the importance on the message. But in the first/bot snippet you are setting a property in the card itself (not sure if that is intentional, but should have no outcome on the message. Just the attachment/card) as well as checking whether `message.IsUrgent` is 'true' (and setting to high if so). Does it work if you just set the message to high specifically (as a test)? Example: `messageActivity.Importance = "high"`

Comment: @DanaV yes I tried to set the importance to "high" regarding the `IsUrgent` property. But still nothing was actually reflected to the message

Comment: Currently there is no support to flag bot messages as important.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT but how is that working when using Graph??

Comment: Yes, it is supported using Graph but not bot.